# Is there any difference between combine and union with respect to the difference operation?

Tags: inkscape

[In this tutorial](https://youtu.be/yYu_24v7LCY?t=447) `union` is used to combine the purple triangles which are then cut from the blue triangle below using difference.
[image: pe]

IIUC we could also use `combine` instead of `union` and it has the same effect as far as the `difference` operation.  As far as boolean operations go, is the effect of using `union` vs `combine` always the same?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends.

If you have overlapping closed paths, the results will be different for Union versus Combine. If not overlapping, then there's no difference. There can also be differences with the behaviour of Combine itself, depending on the direction of paths.

Examples

[image]

Comment: I'm always in awe of how good your answers are!  Thanks!